# Prove that if a spanning set $S$ of $V$ is linear dependent, then the set originated by removing a vector from $S$ will still span $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space spanned by a finite set $S$. If $S$ is a linearly dependent set then if a vector $v$ of $S$ is removed from $S$, the resulting set will still span $V$.

Proof:

Let the vectors of $S$ be $v_1,...,v_i,...,v_n$. Since $S$ is linearly dependent, there exists scalars $x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n$ not all of which are zero such that

$x_1v_1+...,x_iv_i,...+x_nv_n=0$

Assume, without loss of generalization, that $x_i\neq0$. Then

$v_i=(-\frac{x_1}{x_i})v_1+...+(-\frac{x_n}{x_i})v_n$

Since $S$ spans $V$, a vector $\alpha$ from $V$ is of the form

$\alpha=c_1v_1+...+c_iv_i+...+c_nv_n=c_1v_1+...+(-c_i\frac{x_1}{x_i})v_1+...+(-c_i\frac{x_n}{x_i})v_n+c_nv_n=(c_1-c_i\frac{x_1}{x_i})v_1+...+(c_n-c_i\frac{x_n}{x_i})v_n$

This shows that $\alpha$ is written only in terms of the set of vectors in $S$ with $v_i$ removed. Then, this new set spans $V$.

Is this proof valid ?

Comment: No, this is not valid.  It is an excellent exercise to find your mistake!

Comment: Your proof is a good proof of a different statement: if $S$ is a linearly dependent spanning set of $V$, then there is some vector $v \in S$ (your $v_i$) such that $S \setminus \{v\}$ is also a spanning set of $V$. This leads to the correct conclusion that every spanning set contains a basis.

Comment: @RobArthan That was exactly what I was trying to do, I just wrote it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @RuanCarlos: I wondered if that was the case.

Comment: The statement doesn't seem correct as it stands. Consider the set $\{(1,0), (2,0), (0,1)\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$... You "remove a vector" $(0,1)$... $\{(1,0), (2,0)\}$ doesn't span the whole space anymore. The correct claim should be $\exists$ a vector which when removed, the set still spans $V$.

Comment: @Nothingspecial Arrghh, sorry, didn't mean to steal your thunder.  You must have written your comment while I was writing my answer.  LOL.  Considering you used the exact same set I did, you must have a great mind.  (Great minds think alike).

Comment: @nickalh My comment is moot... At the time of posting it, your answer was not yet available and my bad, I didn't read Rob Arthan's comment fully either... The set coincidence is likely because of our bias towards integers and I would guess that $\mathbb R^{n}$ is everyone's favourite space LOL

Answer (score 2):

As stated the theorem is actually false.  @RobArthan gives the
corrected version, I think you want.

The original false statement was

> Let $V$ be a vector space spanned by a finite set $S$. If $S$ is a linearly dependent set then if a vector $v$ of $S$ is removed from $S$, the resulting set will still span $V$.

Consider S = { (1,0), (2,0), (0,1)}.  The span of $S = V = \mathbb{R}^2$.  However, if $S'= S - \lbrace (0,1) \rbrace$, then span$(S') =\mathbb{R}\times \lbrace 0 \rbrace \neq $ span(S).  Thus the original statement is false.

However, a corrected version of the original statement is true.

> Your proof is a good proof of a different statement: if S
> is a linearly dependent spanning set of V, then there is some vector $v_i \in S$, such that $S -{v_i}$ is also a spanning set of V. This leads to the correct conclusion that every spanning set contains a basis.

Comment: I'll edit this to include the original question instead of the corrected question